# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is executed before canEditRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have got a `UITableview`. Everything works except for swipe to the left in order to show Delete button. It seems like the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is executed before `canEditRowAtIndexPath`. How to change to get it to stay and show the delete button instead of showing the new `UIView`?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    println("Edit")
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Select")
    println(indexPath.row)


    let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CklDtljChnge") as! UIViewController

    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these delegate methods in order to do that.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {


        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

          // do  your stuff.

        }
    }
```